# Calling can be used like this?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

> Drug dealer is my new calling

Can you say this instead of saying this:

> Becoming a drug dealer is my new calling

I tried to see if this was idiomatic, but I couldn't find any example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problems grammatically or semantically. However, they have slightly different meanings.

> Becoming a drug dealer is my new calling.

means you are preparing to become a drug dealer, you are learning the craft. You regard the process as a very important job. It interests you, you are keen to become a drug dealer one day.

On the other hand,

> Drug dealer is my new calling.

means you are already an established drug dealer, you find your occupation valuable (thus, calling), and you might have (or have shown) an innate talent for selling drugs.

"calling" in essence means ["vocation, profession, trade, occupation"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/calling#etymonline_v_33251), and I am not sure if it's perfectly accurate to say "drug dealer", which refers to a person who occupies the profession, not to the occupation itself.

> **Selling/pushing drugs** is my calling.

> **Being a drug dealer** is my calling.

Answer (score 2):

That is grammatical. Here's an example from Cambridge Dictionary:

> She believes the medical profession should be thought of as a calling.
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/calling)

Comment: It doesn't sound grammatical to me. Better to say "Dealing drugs is my new calling." To make your example analogous to the OP's example, it would have to be "She believes doctor should be thought of as a calling", which is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is not idiomatic.

We use "calling" for jobs that typically involve service.  For example priests, teachers or nurses.

Drug dealing is the opposite of this. So to say "drug dealing is my calling" suggests you think that criminal selling of drugs is equivalent to teaching or nursing.

You would only say this to make a particular political or social point, and be deliberately non-idiomatic.